# Forming triangles having each of their sizes an integral number of inches not to exceed 2n and 2n-1

Tags: combinatorics, logic

1 )

Show that the number of triangles that can be formed having each of their sides an integral number of inches not exceeding 2n is $\frac16 n(n+1) (4n+5)$

1a) And excluding all equilateral and isosceles triangles it is $\frac16 n(n-1)(4n-5) $

2)

Show that the number of triangles that can be formed having each of their sides an integral number of inches not exceeding (2n-1) is $\frac16 n(n+1)(4n-1)$

2a)And excluding all equilateral and isosceles triangles it is $\frac16 (n-1)(n-2)(4n-3)$

I am working on these questions. If any member knows the correct answers to both these questions including sub-question may provide them.

This question and given answer was taken from the book titled "DCC EXERCISES IN CHOICE AND CHANCE" written by W.A. Whitworth.(late professor from Cambridge University, London, England)

Comment: It is probably worth finding the number of triangles with sides exactly $2n$ or $2n-1$ and then using induction.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answers to both of these questions including sub-question:**

Let us visualize all possible triangles, whose longest side is **x**. Their perimeter must be

**3x, 3x-1, 3x-2,...&c. ... or 2x-1.**

With either perimeter **3x** or **3x-1** we can form only 1 triangle;

With either perimeter **3x-2** or **3x-3** we can form 2 triangles;

With either perimeter **3x-4** or **3x-5** we can form 3 triangles; and so on and so forth.

Hence, the number of possible triangles is

**1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 3 + ... to x terms**

$=\frac14\{ (x+1)^2 - 1\}$ if **x** be even

$=\frac14(x+1)^2$ if **x** be odd.

Or if equilateral and isosceles triangles are excluded, then

With either perimeter **3x-3** or **3x-4** we can form 1 triangle;

With either perimeter **3x-5** or **3x-6** we can form 2 triangles;

With either perimeter **3x-7** or **3x-8** we can form 3 triangles; and so on and so forth.

Hence the number of possible triangles is

**1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 3 + ... to  x-3 terms.**

$= \frac14(x-2)^2$ if **x** be even

$=\frac14\{(x-2)^2-1\}$ if **x** be odd.

For question 1),

we have to give **x** all values from 1 to 2n and sum. Hence the number of triangles is

Answer to 1)$$\frac14\displaystyle\sum_{1}^{2n}\{(x+1)^2\}-\frac14n = \frac16 n(n+1) (4n+5)$$

Or if equilateral or isosceles triangles are excluded, the number of triangles is

Answer to 1a) $$\frac14\displaystyle\sum_{4}^{2n}\{(x-2)^2\}-\frac14(n-2)= \frac16 n(n-1)(4n-5)$$

For question 2),

we have to give **x** all values from 1 to 2n-1 and we have the number of triangles is equal to

Answer to 2)$$\frac14\displaystyle\sum_{1}^{2n-1}\{(x+1)^2\}-\frac14 (n-1)=\frac16 n(n+1)(4n-1)$$

And when equilateral and isosceles triangles are excluded, we have the number of triangles is equal to

Answer to 2a)$$\frac14\displaystyle\sum_{4}^{2n-1}\{(x-2)^2\}-\frac14(n-2)=\frac16 (n-1) (n-2)(4n-3)$$

Comment: This question has already been answered correctly and accepted by original poster.